# Transferring Plugins and files to new ADT version 23?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So, I have just downloaded and run the new version of the Eclipse/ADT, after finding out that I couldn't update previous version I had. However, last night I downloaded all the Google Play services SDK packages and things on my previous version. So, upon finding out that I had to update my Eclipse/ADT to use the newly acquired SDKs, I downloaded the new version.

My problem is this: When I went to the SDK manager to install the new SDKs over again, since I figured I would now that I have this new ADT bundle, the SDK manager said that I already had installed the SDKs. But those SDKs are in my older ADT bundle folder, not the new one I downloaded today. So, would I be able to simply transfer/copy over the downloaded SDKs from the older ADT folder to the new one?

I apologize if this sounds confusing. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I never knew if I could copy and paste them over, so I just went and deleted and uninstalled the previous version and just re-downloaded the SDKs into the version 23 folder. Took basically the whole day to download all the files (94 files, to be exact), but everything is normal and fine now.